# Hide HTML but keep it visible

Tags: html, dialog, accessibility, tabindex

I need to implement some kind of modal in HTML/JavaScript. When the modal is open, the page should still be visible in the background, but it should not be accessible with the keyboard and should also not be included in screen reader output. In other word, I want it to act as if it was not there, but still be visible.

I also looked through the proposed "dialog" spec and found a definition of [inert](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#inert) that describes perfectly what I need:

> When a node is inert, then the user agent must act as if the node was absent for the purposes of targeting user interaction events

What I tried (I was not able to test with a screen reader, so I only tested keyboard access):

- Set `hidden` and `style="display: block"` on the page element.
- Set `tabindex="-1"` and `aria-hidden="true"`on the page element.

As you might guess, none of these worked.

Is there some sensible way to make a subtree "inert" with current technology?

Comment: You can create a modal inside a div with `position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); z-index: 1` to emulate a foreground where your modal will reside and a faded background, where your page is still visible.

Answer (score 3):

To date `inert` is not supported by [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=921504) nor [Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269846) and was [dropped from the WHATWG version](https://github.com/whatwg/html/commit/5ddfc78b1f82e86cc202d72ccc752a0e15f1e4ad) of the spec in 2014.

A resource to identify *how* a modal should work is [provided in the ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/#dialog_modal).

For more detail I suggest [Marco Zehe's advice on accessible modals](https://www.marcozehe.de/2015/02/05/advanced-aria-tip-2-accessible-modal-dialogs/). Marco works for Firefox. There are also some very valuable tips and references in the comments.

All of those are a little much to paste in here.

Comment: Nice, great answer. I build my dialogs pretty much exactly Marco explained, and they work perfectly. I just want to add (I didn't see this important part in his post) that to stop a screen reader from reading the page underneath the dialog, you need to wrap your page in a <div> and set `aria-hidden="true"`. You also have to render your dialog outside this <div>, so screen readers cannot read the page, and since your focus is trapped in the dialog (read Marco's tutorial), both keyboard and screen readers will not read outside the dialog, until you close.

Comment: As far as I understand the article suggests to trap the keyboard focus within the modal. This seems like an incomplete hack to me. As I understand, there are other means of navigation, e.g. document outline.

Comment: Yep, there are, but for users who are not using screen readers trapping focus inside the modal does the job. For users who are using screen readers, this reinforces the need to have clear labeling for your modal.

Answer (score 0):

The `dialog` element works in Chrome, Safari and Opera. This achieve your needs for inertness for other elements when calling the `showModal()` function on a `dialog` element.

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('modal').showModal();">click here</a>

<dialog id="modal">
  hello
</dialog>
```

The most important thing is to understand that your page pointed out that:

> This section does not define or create any content attribute named "inert". This section merely defines an abstract concept of inertness.

The best thing to do is to use the `showModal()` function as it works on different browsers, hoping that it will be soon implemented in Firefox and IE browsers.

Answer (score -1):

We usually create a container (eg, `<div>`) the same size as the page but with a z-index greater than the main page.  That effectively hides the main page from user input.  We then have our modal dialog 'on top' of the container by having a z-index bigger than the container.